# Two views 1 Model MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When using MVC to capture information in a form, can I break up the from in two views but still use a single model, and write to the db at the last form?

For example Account.cs model has name and surname
I want view1 to capture name, view2 to capture surname and when i click submit it must write to the db.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a model on however many views you like.  In fact, one of the features of MVC is that it allows you to use the same model and controller action with different views to present the same data in difference way.

However, in this case, you will be responsible for getting the data from the first view into the second view, so the submit action can write both together.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to use a single form across two views. However, you can use two forms for the two views, using a single model. In view1, capture the name and call the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult(Account model)
{
    return View("View2", model");
}
```

Then, simply use a hidden input to store the information from view1 in the form in view2:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Surname)
    </div>
}
```